# Show enclosing #ifdef blocks in Emacs

Tags: emacs, macros, elisp

Is it possible to show current #ifdef blocks in Emacs (eg in mode-line)?

For example:

```
#ifdef A
... | #cursor position num. 1
#ifdef !B & C
...
#else /* !B & C */
foo(); | #cursor position num. 2
#endif /* !B & C */
#endif /* A */
```

It should show `A` in mode line, if I put cursor in position 1 
and show `A & !(!B & C)` in position 2.
I am already using hide-if-def mode. But sometimes i need to work with all #ifdef blocks.

Comment: Not an answer, but it's quite useful to do `C-c C-u` to jump up to the nearest enclosing `#ifdef`. You can then use `C-u C-<SPC>` to return to where you were.

Answer (score 3):

I've not always had success with [WhichFunction](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhichFuncMode), but it should work with C/C++ code nicely.  This customization will add a new function to the recognition scheme which will tell you when you're inside an #ifdef block.

```
(require 'which-func)
(which-function-mode 1)
(defun name-of-current-conditional ()
  "rather inelegant coding, but it works"
  (interactive)
  (let (outer)
    (condition-case nil
        (dotimes (myv 10)
          (save-excursion
            (c-up-conditional (1+ myv))
            (setq outer (buffer-substring-no-properties 
                              (line-beginning-position)
                              (line-end-position)))))
      (error nil))
    outer))
(setq which-func-functions '(name-of-current-conditional))
```

Comment: Thank you for your work, but i think that it is usefull only in case of using simple ifdef`s. It shows "ifdef A" when i am under "else". I would like to see "ifdef !A" or "ifndef A" in this case. It also doesn't handle complex "ifdefs". I have a lot of nested ifdefs in my project. Maybe it's almost impossible to have feature like that.

Comment: @folq - Right, you want code to do the actual boolean logic on the clauses as you march out.  You could use my code to start to put that together, but that's a larger task than I'm wanting to take on.